# The namespace of element 'enumeration' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xjc

I am getting this error when validating enumeration element in xsd.

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
               <enumeration value="4">
       </enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
```

Please help me regarding this.

```
 s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'enumeration' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `enumeration` element need to be bound the XML Schema. You need to add the prefix, namely `xsd`, like so :

```
<xsd:enumeration>
```

Comment: OK. It looks like you've been fastest however.

Comment: You were clearly already answering too, so let's call it a tie.

Comment: this is correct. i agree. but when i am passed alphabets or special characters. it is not validating. it is allowing.

Answer (score 2):

Add the namespace prefix `xsd:` to `enumeration`:

```
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedInt">
  <xsd:enumeration value="4"/>
</xsd:restriction>
```

Comment: you are correct. But If i passed special characters, it is allowing. it is not validating with string characters.

Comment: You clearly have to have the `xsd:` prefix on `enumeration` to get past your error.   If you're having further trouble with special characters, you'll have to add more detail to your question (or, better, ask a new question), and we'll try to help with that problem.  Be sure to post a minimal but complete example (XML and XSD) that shows the issue.  Thanks.